# Opening Excel files from C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have an issue when working with Excel from C# using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel object.

The problem comes when I try and open a file to write to that I have already have open in Excel. This ultimately errors and then leaves an instance of Excel running in the background.

How can I tell that the file is already open before opening it?

Also what is the convention for disposing with the Excel objects and therefore killing the Excel process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following article provides a good way of checking if a file is open already:

[Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

This article talks about killing the excel process:

[Kill Process Excel C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316141/kill-process-excel-c-sharp)

Hope these are helpful

Answer (score 0):

Hello you must to dispose your excel objects at end of treatment (workbook, applicationClass, usedRange, worksheet)

```
        workbook.Close(false, workbookPath, null);
        applicationClass.Quit();

        while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(usedRange) > 0)
        { }
        while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet) > 0)
        { }
        while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook) > 0)
        { }
        while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(applicationClass) > 0)
        { }
```

Answer (score 0):

For opening of already opened - for more just type Workbooks.Open on the MSDN.
Here is the save sample, you just overwrite (an still opened) without querying :o),
***xlShared*** and ***xlLocalSessionChanges*** are keywords.

```
            _xlsWorkbook.SaveAs(
                 targetFileName                                                     /* Filename */
                ,Excel_ForMissing.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8                             /* FileFormat */
                ,Missing.Value                                                      /* Password */
                ,Missing.Value                                                      /* WriteResPassword */
                ,Missing.Value                                                      /* ReadOnlyRecommended */
                ,Missing.Value                                                      /* CreateBackup */
                ,Excel_ForMissing.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared                       /* AccessMode */
                ,Excel_ForMissing.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges    /* ConflictResolution */
                ,false                                                       /* AddToMru */
                ,Missing.Value                                                       /* TextCodepage */
                ,Missing.Value                                                       /* TextVisualLayout */
                ,true                                                       /* Local */
            );
```