# C# Interop not closing Excel process after execution

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop

I have the following blocks of code:

```
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(this.pathToFile);
    Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
    Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
```

I push the xlRange into an array using:

```
someArray = (System.Object[,])xlRange.Value2;
```

Afterwards I try to cleanup with:

```
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

    xlWorkbook.Close();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
    xlApp.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

However, even with all four of the excel objects being released with `Marshal`, the process stays open and prevents the file from being opened again.

Any ideas as to how to properly clean up `Interop` excel objects?

Comment: I guess this is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960693/excel-process-doesnt-get-closed.
Did you try the solution suggested there ?

Comment: Hae a look [at the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects?rq=1) Your problem is that you are using Workbook.Open, Try Excel.Workbooks xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks, Excel.Worbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(this,pathtofile); then make sure to add release workbooks, and set null everything and run garbage collector. Same with your Sheets and worksheet. With com object NEVER have 2 dots on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and managed to close the application following this processs;

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlRange);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

xlWorkbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

xlApp.Quit();
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```