# TFS SDK: Query yesterday's builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

I can query for all builds within a TeamProject as follows:

```
  var bServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<IBuildServer>();
  IBuildDetail[] builds = bServer.QueryBuilds("myTeamProject");
```

This yields all `builds` within the given `myTeamProject`. But I am only interested in yesterday's builds. 
 I can obviously filter after I 've gotten the results within `builds`. 
Still I am wondering if there exists an overload of `QueryBuilds()` to get builds within a provided timespan.

---

Background:
In my original TFS build solution, a custom code activity would get catch the `BuildDetail` properties that are important to us & would add them in an Excel sheet using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
This was rather convenient, since it took place during Build & our "BuildLog.xls" was always up-to-date.

Unfortunately this lead to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383953/tfs-2010-build-sporadic-failure-in-the-process) issue, so I had to remove the code activity & I am currently implementing Plan B: 
A console application scheduled to kick-in once a day, that queries for yesterday's builds & adds them in my Excel file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an [IBuildDetailSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetailspec.aspx) object and specify the MaxFinishTime (the end of the time range) and MinFinishTime (the beginning of the time range) to get builds in a range.

IBuildServer has a method to create IBuildDetailSpec and a QueryBuilds method to query with this spec.

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed - thank you very much. More useful info is also available here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/68beb94c-f3a2-4303-9d5b-894c58be8258/