# TFS: Query for builds containing a specific changeset

Tags: build, tfs-sdk

I have a number of build definitions that get executed based upon a single branch in TFS (eg Main).

I'd like to (somehow) query TFS to find all builds containing a specific changeset number that I supply, and return a list of string of the names of the builds that TFS contains.  Any kind of app (VS extension, CLI app, winforms, whatever) will do.

Note:  this isn't a 'plz give me the code' request; I'm willing to hoof it and do serious work on this.  Any pointers to documentation on how to query the database or SDK, or an example of how to query builds; just some place to start looking would be extremely helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following snippet will crawl all Build Definitions of all Team Project of a Collection, and will check each and every build for an Association to the input changeset number:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace FindChangesetInBuild
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs:8080/tfs/collectionName"));

            var versionControl = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            var buildService = (IBuildServer)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

            var teamProjects = versionControl.GetAllTeamProjects(true);
            foreach (var teamProject in teamProjects)
            {
                var buildDefinitions = buildService.QueryBuildDefinitions(teamProject.Name);
                foreach (var buildDefinition in buildDefinitions)
                {
                    var builds = buildService.QueryBuilds(buildDefinition);
                    foreach (var buildDetail in builds)
                    {
                        var changesets = InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets(buildDetail);
                        if (changesets.Any(changesetSummary => changesetSummary.ChangesetId == Convert.ToInt32(args[0])))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Changeset was build in "+buildDetail.BuildNumber);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Needless to say, this is a brute force attack.
You can further refine the code if you narrow down the list of `buildDefinition`, make focus on specific `teamProjects` etc. In any case I can hardly imagine the above to be useful as-is!
Apart from (obviously) [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), a great resource for TFS-SDK is Shai Raiten's [blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/05/18/tfs-api-index-parts-1-to-37.aspx).
For Build-Speficic examples, check also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914104/tfs-sdk-query-yesterdays-builds) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263005/tfs-api-how-to-query-builds-independent-of-which-build-definition-they-belong) for some possibly interesting SO posts.

Comment: Thank you!  I wish there were more filtering options available when querying; we have a number of builds that we are retaining information for and it takes a very long time for queries to return.  I'll experiment and see.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this little DB Query in TFS 2010 and just substitute 90264 with your changeset id.

```sql
USE Tfs_Warehouse
go
SELECT BuildName 
FROM DimBuild
   INNER JOIN FactBuildChangeset
   ON DimBuild.BuildSK = FactBuildChangeset.BuildSK
WHERE FactBuildChangeset.ChangesetSK = 90264
```